# Wordpress returns IP address instead of domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, proxy

This was working for years until I did something that has now jacked this up....

Searching on this topic landed me in several places that basically said: You need to check the Wordpress URL and the site URL in the general settings in Wordpress.  I have done so and they are both: http://www.petesworkshop.com/blog_wp .  Yet, when I hit that URL I am redirected to my internal IP and get a error `http://10.0.10.206/blog_wp` (yep, that would be wrong!

Interestingly enough, I can get to the admin page just fine and it is just a subfolder of blog_wp.  So, somehow things directed to /blog_wp return the IP but everything else is OK.  Wierd.

Wordpress sits behind an Apache proxy which has this directive for the virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.petesworkshop.com
ServerAlias petesworkshop.com

ProxyPass / http://10.0.10.206:5080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.10.206:5080/

</VirtualHost>
```

The server running the website behind the proxy has this:

```
DocumentRoot "/www/petes/htdocs/petesworkshop/"
ServerName www.petesworkshop.com
ServerAlias petesworkshop.com
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm
ErrorLog logs/petesworkshop.log
Options FollowSymLinks

Alias /blog_wp  /www/petes/htdocs/petesworkshop/blog_wp

<Directory /www/petes/htdocs/petesworkshop/blog_wp >
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow From all
</Directory>

<Directory /www/petes/htdocs/petesworkshop >
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow From all
</Directory>
```

I am not sure how I jacked this up...it is probably something that I did to the Apache configuration but I can't be sure since everything else behind the proxy works fine.  I even tried adding specific ProxyPass entries for /blog_wp but that didn't make any difference.

Stumped...

Answer (score 0):

Check your wp-config.php for correct urls

like below

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Comment: I mentioned that in the open description: "They are both set to: http://www.petesworkshop.com/blog_wp  That is why I am so confused here and why I *suspect* it is an Apache config issue (although I don't get that either since other proxy statements are working OK)

Answer (score 0):

This one turned out to be an Apache proxy issue.  What I needed was to add 'ProxyPreserveHost On' to the configuration, which I *thought* I had in there originally but I either removed it in an edit or had it placed in the wrong virtual host. In any case, adding the ProxyPreserveHost On flag, took care of the issue.  Not sure why other entries in the same virtual host DID work without it but I am not going to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some time ago, whenever I wrote my domain in the browser it was solved correctly but my domain name was changed by the IP, after much research it turned out that the problem was in the hosting, not in the server, so which only change the configuration of my domain in GoDaddy since I was only doing a redirection but the correct thing was to create an A record that points to @ (which represents your domain name) and everything started to work correctly. I hope it's help